# Use command options (like -f) from Perforce Visual Client

Tags: perforce

I get an error while adding few files to Perforce which has WILDCARD characters in their name. The error is clear, asking to use the '-f' option while running p4 add.
Now I am using the p4 visual client app on my work machine and could not find a way to add options while running the command. Is this something that we can do only on the command line ?

P.S -  I am on a corporate network. And I don't have rights to install softwares freely from internet and as such can't install the perforce command line.

Answer (score 1):

P4V *should* give you the option to add the files (i.e. it should use the `-f` option for you when appropriate).  If it's instead giving you the command line error message that sounds buggy; I'd recommend raising it with Perforce tech support.

I would also recommend negotiating with your IT team to allow you to install the p4 command line tool; if they've already approved P4V there's no earthly reason to not approve P4 (which is just a very thin wrapper around the p4 client libraries that P4V is built on, and also completely open-source so therefore easily auditable).  Once you're able to run the appropriate `p4 add` command, the server commands will return the escaped versions of the wildcards and other commands based on those escaped paths will work without any special handling, so P4V might just work correctly from that point on.